# Ошибка в потоке кода C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;

class SampleClass
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass();
        sampleClass.SayHello();
    }
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Поток 0x7a4 завершился с кодом 259 (0x103).


Поток 0xd58 завершился с кодом 259 (0x103).


Программа "[2732] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe" завершилась с кодом 0 (0x0).
```

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: @IInyr почему вы посчитали, что это ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никакой ошибки нет. Это вспомогательные отладочные потоки Visual Studio, которые бегут в контексте вашего процесса (даже скорее всего не вашего, а .vshost). Можете смело игнорировать, если в окне вывода нет исключений (их ни с чем не спутать) и приложение успешно добегает до конца.